# Filtering out nodes on two cypher paths

Tags: neo4j, pattern-matching, cypher

I have a simplified Neo4j graph (old version 2.x) as the image with 'defines' and 'same' edges. Assume the number on the `define` edge is a property on the edge

The queries I would like to run are:

1) Find nodes `defined` by both A and B -- Requried result: C, C, D

`START A=node(885), B=node(996) MATCH (A-[:define]->(x)<-[:define]-B) RETURN DISTINCT x`

Above works and returns C and D. But I want C twice since its defined twice. But without the distinct on x, it returns all the paths from A to B.

2)Find nodes that are NOT (defined by both A,B OR are defined by both A,B but connected via a same edge) -- Required result: G

Something like:

`R1: MATCH (A-[:define]->(x)<-[:define]-B) RETURN DISTINCT x`

`R2: MATCH (A-[:define]->(e)-(:similar)-(f)<-[:define]-B) RETURN e,f`

(Nodes defined by A - (R1+R2) )

3) Find 'middle' nodes that do not have matching calls from both A and B --Required result: C,G

I want to output C due to the 1 `define`(either 45/46) that does not have a matching define from B. 
Also output G because there's no `define` to G from B.
[image]

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using? The missing parenthesis on your match doesn't look like it should run in Neo4j 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit strange to me, so I'm going to assume you're using an older version of Neo4j. We should be able to use the same approaches, though.

For #1, Your proposed match without distinct really should be working. The only thing I can see is adding missing parenthesis around A and B node variables.

```
START A=node(885), B=node(996) 
MATCH (A)-[:define]->(x)<-[:define]-(B) 
RETURN x
```

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "returns all paths from A to B." Can you clarify that, and provide an example of the output?

As for #2, we'll need several several parts to this query, separating them with WITH accordingly.

```
START A=node(885), B=node(996) 
MATCH (A)-[:define]->(x)<-[:define]-(B)
WITH A, B, COLLECT(DISTINCT x) as exceptions
OPTIONAL MATCH (A)-[:define]->(x)-[:same]-(y)<-[:define]-(B)
WHERE x NOT IN exceptions AND y NOT IN exceptions
WITH A, B, exceptions + COLLECT(DISTINCT x) + COLLECT(DISTINCT y) as allExceptions
MATCH (aNode)
WHERE aNode NOT IN allExceptions AND aNode <> A AND aNode <> B
RETURN aNode
```

Also, you should really be using labels on your nodes. The final match will match all nodes in your graph and will have to filter down otherwise.

EDIT

Regarding your #3 requirement, the SIZE() function will be very helpful here, as you can get the size of a pattern match, and it will tell you the number of occurrences of that pattern.

The approach on this query is to first get the collection of nodes defined by A or B, then filter down to the nodes where the number of :defines relationships from A are not equal to the number of :defines relationships from B.

While we would like to use something like a UNION WITH in order to get the union of nodes defined by A and union it with the nodes defined by B, Neo4j's UNION support is weak right now, as it doesn't let you do any additional operations after the UNION happens, so instead we have to resort to adding both sets of nodes into the same collection then unwinding them back into rows.

```
START A=node(885), B=node(996) 
MATCH (A)-[:define]->(x)
WITH A, B, COLLECT(x) as middleNodes
MATCH (B)-[:define]->(x) 
WITH A, B, middleNodes + COLLECT(x) as allMiddles
UNWIND allMiddles as middle
WITH DISTINCT A, B, middle
WHERE SIZE((A)-[:define]->(middle)) <> SIZE((B)-[:define]->(middle))
RETURN middle
```

Comment: Thanks lot for your answer. Looking at that, I realized a test case I'm not handling hence updated my question with query #3. appreciate your input on this.

Comment: Updated to provide a query for #3 and an explanation of the approach.

Comment: Shouldn't the `middleNodes + COLLECT(x)` in `WITH A, B, middleNodes + COLLECT(x)` line be renamed with `AS`?

Comment: Yes, it should, thank you for catching that. I fixed the query accordingly.

Comment: one final question: the answer to #3 correctly returns, E, F, C and G. I've been playing around a bit (but failed) to remove E and F -- since E and F are both defined by A,B and are similar, I would like to remove them from the result by doing an optional match... any suggestions?

Comment: It seems like a reasonable approach, and between the queries given, you should have the pieces necessary to construct that query. Give it one last try, and add your attempted query to your description if it's still giving you some trouble. I'll see what I can add tomorrow.

Comment: I ended up doing this in the API, will get back to thinking about the cypher version soon, thanks for your help!